# Using Views to List a Member's Organic Groups (7.x-2.3)

Tags: organic-groups, views

I am migrating a site from using OG 7.x-1.4 to OG 7.x-2.3. The migration seemed to go fine, but it broke the view that shows the current users group (i.e. groups the user is a member of). In the original view for 1.4, it had a contextual filter:

- (OG membership from OG group) We pass to the "Entity ID" the User ID.

And the following relationships:

- OG group: OG group from Node
- (node being the OG group) OG group: OG membership from OG group

However, the new Organic Groups 7.x-2.3 now uses the OGMembership data model and I cannot figure out how to recreate this view using OGMembership, as I am not clear exactly how it works and I cannot seem to find any in-depth documentation for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how to get the OG membership ID:s to start with.

Add new view.
Show -> OG membership (important!)
Then in some display add a contextual filter -> OG membership: Entity id.
Provide default value -> Type -> User ID from logged in user.
Override title: %1's groups.
Specify validation criteria -> User.

Now you have the list of ID:s.

Next to get the actual titles of the groups (as the base table is OG membership, not node), Add a relationship -> Group Node from OG membership.
Add a field -> Content: Title.
Relationship -> Group node from OG membership.

Now you have the titles too. Add some filters and sort criterias to taste.

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answer. That worked like a charm! I did not realize you could create a view of OG memberships. That was an eye opener. If it's permissible to ask a follow up question, can you tell me how I'd show the number of members in each group?

Comment: No, sorry. Here is the discussion everybody is linking to: http://drupal.org/node/1101102

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer. It helps you, me, and the community. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't understand. I tried to upvote but didn't have a high enough reputation, and I didn't see the checkmark icon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the export for a view that does the job as described by Kari Kääriäinen above.

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'my_groups';
$view->description = 'List of Groups I\'m Subscribed To';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'og_membership';
$view->human_name = 'My Groups';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'My Groups';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['role'] = array(
  2 => '2',
);
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '200';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['quantity'] = '9';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
/* Field: OG membership: Delete link */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['delete_membership']['id'] = 'delete_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['delete_membership']['table'] = 'og_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['delete_membership']['field'] = 'delete_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['delete_membership']['label'] = 'Remove';
/* Field: OG membership: Edit link */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_membership']['id'] = 'edit_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_membership']['table'] = 'og_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_membership']['field'] = 'edit_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_membership']['label'] = 'Edit';
/* Field: OG membership: Rendered OG membership */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['id'] = 'rendered_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['table'] = 'views_entity_og_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['field'] = 'rendered_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['link_to_entity'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['bypass_access'] = 0;
/* Contextual filter: OG membership: Entity id */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['id'] = 'etid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['table'] = 'og_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['field'] = 'etid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['default_argument_type'] = 'current_user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'my_groups';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'My Groups';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['description'] = 'Groups that I am subscribed to';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;
$translatables['my_groups'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('My Groups'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Items per page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Offset'),
  t('« first'),
  t('‹ previous'),
  t('next ›'),
  t('last »'),
  t('Remove'),
  t('Edit'),
  t('Rendered OG membership'),
  t('All'),
  t('Page'),
);

$view = new view();
$view->name = 'my_groups';
$view->description = 'List of Groups I\'m Subscribed To';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'og_membership';
$view->human_name = 'My Groups';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'My Groups';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['role'] = array(
  2 => '2',
);
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '200';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['quantity'] = '9';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
/* Field: OG membership: Delete link */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['delete_membership']['id'] = 'delete_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['delete_membership']['table'] = 'og_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['delete_membership']['field'] = 'delete_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['delete_membership']['label'] = 'Remove';
/* Field: OG membership: Edit link */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_membership']['id'] = 'edit_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_membership']['table'] = 'og_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_membership']['field'] = 'edit_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_membership']['label'] = 'Edit';
/* Field: OG membership: Rendered OG membership */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['id'] = 'rendered_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['table'] = 'views_entity_og_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['field'] = 'rendered_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['link_to_entity'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['bypass_access'] = 0;
/* Contextual filter: OG membership: Entity id */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['id'] = 'etid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['table'] = 'og_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['field'] = 'etid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['default_argument_type'] = 'current_user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['etid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'my_groups';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'My Groups';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['description'] = 'Groups that I am subscribed to';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;
$translatables['my_groups'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('My Groups'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Items per page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Offset'),
  t('« first'),
  t('‹ previous'),
  t('next ›'),
  t('last »'),
  t('Remove'),
  t('Edit'),
  t('Rendered OG membership'),
  t('All'),
  t('Page'),
);
```