# Organic Groups - Display the Group Name that a peice of content belongs to

Tags: views, organic-groups

I have a view that is listing all of the content tagged with a taxonomy terms (contextual filter).  Underneath the note title, I would like to include some meta that says: posted by username who belongs to "**group name**" and link that over to the associated group. Here is a screenshot of my current view:

http://cl.ly/image/0Z103y3q3D1z

Any help is much appreciated. I can't seem to find a "group name" or "group title" field anywhere when attempting to use fields associated with a relationship.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer with the help of this post: [Using Views to List a Member's Organic Groups (7.x-2.3)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84500/using-views-to-list-a-members-organic-groups-7-x-2-3)

Here is a screeshot of my view: http://cl.ly/image/2O1h1x3T3J43

by adding the relationship: "OG Membership: Group Node from OG membership" I was able to use that relationship in a new title field and display.