# How do I add a list of members

Tags: routes

I have added users and want to display a list of members as a block in a space on Open Atrium. I have looked in menus and Open Atrium when trying to add content but cannot find anything that will allow me to do this?

Comment: you could find possible related answer at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84500/using-views-to-list-a-members-organic-groups-7-x-2-3

Answer (score 1):

Theres a widget called "OG members" that could help you.

When in a space, you have this button to personalize the display. Click it then you can add widget (the '+' button). In the new window, you can find widgets that you can add and configure as you need. 
Theres one called 'OG Members' in the category called (I think) 'Panel panes'.
I think this widget is meant to display members of the space you visiting

Comment: Could you elaborate? Screenshot? Link? Instruction how to turn it on?