# Using View to List a Member's Organic Group with Inherited membership

Tags: views, organic-groups

I am looking to create a view which will return any content a user has membership to.

Following steps from another post, I managed to return content which matches users membership. But this doesn't take into account content where membership is inherited. So a node which is linked to another node's audience doesn't appear in the view. 
Steps taken:

- Add new view. `Show -> OG membership` (***important!***)
- Then in some display add a contextual filter:

  `OG membership: Entity id.`

  Provide default value: `Type -> User ID` from logged in user
- Next to get the actual titles of the groups (as the base table is OG
  membership, not node),
- Add a relationship -> `Group Node from OG membership`.
- Add a field -> `Content: Title. Relationship` -> Group node from OG
  membership.

[Using Views to List a Member's Organic Groups (7.x-2.3)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84500/using-views-to-list-a-members-organic-groups-7-x-2-3)

Answer (score 0):

After digging around in the default views, I found a work around for my problem.

I cloned the view **OG User groups (OG membership)** which is normally attached to the user profile. I then filtered content against some custom fields to resolve my problem.

Its a work around admittedly, but I would advise people to check some of the other default views or the og_extras module for additional views.